# How to define totally new asset types in WSO2 G-REG?

Tags: wso2

I am evaluating WSO2 G-REG and would like to create some new asset types like Integration (similar to a service but with other attributes and with other life-cycle stages) and Application (basically a consumer of service(s) that itself does not expose any endpoints and that once again has its own set of life cycle stages).

I have seen some examples about how to add attributes to existing asset types (and to modify there life cycle stages) but so far not figured out how to create new ones (from the product feature list I get the impression it should be possible)...

Pointers to documentation or even better some examples or XML snippets are warmly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can find some information in [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance411/Configurable+Governance+Artifacts).

Thanks,
Senaka.